# Best way to change kernel of Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 22.04

What is the best way to use the current stable kernel in ubuntu 22.04 LTS? I need kernel 5.16+ for some of my hardware to work well. So, I'm looking for a safe way to change 22.05 kernel.
PS. I also have an Nvidia GPU. Will changing kernel have any issues with the GPU?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a mainline kernel from [Ubuntu Kernel PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/).

But mainline kernels are not officially supported and it is not guaranteed that Nvidia proprietary drivers will build with that kernel.

Comment: How about the cappelikan PPA? Say I install the 5.17.15 stable kernel using ubuntu-mainline-kernel-installer, will it have Nvidia driver with it? And how can I find if a kernel has Nvidia driver?

Comment: I have no idea what "cappelikan PPA" is. Linux kernel contains open-source Nvidia drivers, but proprietary drivers don't have to build with every kernel.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

It will provide the *"HardWare Enablement"* kernel backport from 23.04. This is the `6.2` version. Not sure about the GPU though.